# Error "relation does not exist" while restoring db and when relations already exist

Tags: database, postgresql, psql

I'm trying to recover my db from server in local. I have db.bak file that contains all database.
I used this command in psql:

```
    CREATE DATABASE my_db;
```

then in root I used:

```
    sudo -u postgres psql my_db < db.bak;
```

all tables are recovered except 4 of them, while the tables exist in the .bak file. But on another computer all tables have been recovered correctly.

Answer (score 0):

the problem was in installation of postgit. it should be installed by this command:

```
sudo apt install postgresql-10
sudo apt install postgresql-10-postgis-2.4
sudo apt install postgresql-10-postgis-scripts
```

it solved my problem.